# How to connect two sets of vertices with each other

Tags: vertices, selection-tools, vertex-groups

I know that I can select and then join 2 verts with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

I want to know if there is an easy way to connect a large number of points in pairs or I have to select each pair separately and press the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>?

---

**Update 1**

I think it is better to explain my questions with a picture :)

I want to go from the model on the right to the model on the left. Well now I know this is possible by selecting any point on the top plane and connecting it to the bottom plane using the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> keys.

[image]

But when the number of these points increases, it becomes difficult. I wanted to know if there is a way to do this automatically?

I tried one of the methods mentioned in the comments. Use the <kbd>F</kbd> key to generate the FACE. This method works but there is a problem. It does not create Edges between the points and when you want to subdivide the shape, it gets in trouble.

As you can see in next picture:

[image]

Comment: but connected how? in a face or separate row of loose vertices? if they are loose try selecting all of them and press f, and then select the face and press x and select only faces....if you want a "path" of vertices of the face, use knife cut for messy topology (ngons) and for quad topology select 2 or more vertices and use the j to create a path...

Comment: Hi @MichaelBenDavid :) thanks for your comment; I will test this solution :)

Comment: It would help to have an illustration / toy example of what you mean by 'pairs'.

Comment: @RobinBetts Hi :) i updated my answer

Comment: @MichaelBenDavid I did not understand how to use "j" to generate "path" but i tested the "F" key solution :) It works; But in the case of subdivision, it kind of falls apart.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertex/connect_vertex_path.html

Comment: @MichaelBenDavid WoW thanks a lot for this link. its an amazing feature i did not know that exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> Edge Menu > *Bridge Edge Loops*, 'Blend Surface', with one cut.

[image]

If this is not exactly what you're after, have a play with the other settings (e.g. 'Merge') to get the sense of them.

Comment: Thank you so much; Works great :)

Comment: Khahesh mikonam